# PVC Stripping issue on steel wire with pulley

Tags: design, machine-design, pulleys, maintenance

I am having some issues with a PVC coated steel cable. The PVC often strips when used with a pulley.

I wanted to know why this may be happening and possible solutions for it.

Comment: as Mike says, stop using coated wire rope in a pully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pvc coating is designed for cables in the open as a protection from dust, the elements etc.

If the pvc coated cable is going over a pulley then the pvc coating is subjected to crushing and tearing forces that exceed its design parameters.

You likely are using the wrong cable or using a cable outside of its designed use.

Consider other solutions ie different cables or a different design of mechanism, difficult to have any suggestions as your question lacks any useful detail.

Comment: The steel elastic limit is over 0,5% strain ( depending on strength)  while the plastic goes into plastic strain at lower levels . So the plastic is failing in fatigue  while the steel in only in the elastic strain range.